# Add list content from yaml to configmap | openshift | expect char '"' but got char '['

Tags: list, kubernetes, yaml, openshift, configmap

I am trying to create ConfigMap in OpenShift by using YAML file.

My YAML is having a list of values as below.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: sample-map-json-fields
  namespace: default
data:
  fields:
    - hello
    - world
    - my.test.field
```

I executed like below -

```
 oc create -f filename.yaml
```

Getting exception like below -

> Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "filename.yaml":
> ConfigMap in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: [pos 42]:
> json: expect char '"' but got char '['

If I do the same without list content inside data, it works.

Please help how to handle the YAML list for ConfigMap.

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because you are providing `array` whereas Kubernetes expects to receive `string` .

```
got "array", expected "string"
```

Please read more about [configMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#configmap-v1-core) in Kubernetes API documentation:

```
data  - _object_   

Data contains the configuration data. Each key must
consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.'. Values with
non-UTF-8 byte sequences must use the BinaryData field. The keys
stored in Data must not overlap with the keys in the BinaryData field,
this is enforced during validation process.
```

Or in the go [docs](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/core/v1#ConfigMap):

```
// Data contains the configuration data.
// Each key must consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.'.
// Values with non-UTF-8 byte sequences must use the BinaryData field.
// The keys stored in Data must not overlap with the keys in
// the BinaryData field, this is enforced during validation process.
// +optional


Data map[string]string `json:"data,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,2,rep,name=data"`
```

Comment: So its not possible to use list ?

Comment: It it not possible, you have to use [multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines/21699210#21699210)